# purpose of keeping some flag register bits "reserved" in 8086?

Tags: assembly, intel, flags, cpu-registers, x86-16

In the flag register of intel 8086 processor,what is the purpose of keeping the bits 12,13,14 and 15 **reserved**? 
For example are they useful in the assembly shift commands such as SAR and SHR or they're kept reserved for testing purposes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

They're reserved for future use. In other words, if you use them or depend on them being a certain value, your code may break in the future.

More flags were indeed added in 80286 and newer processors in the "reserved flags", and the register was even extended to 32 bits. You can get an overview of the new flags and when they were added [here](http://zsmith.co/intel.html#flags).